# ng-show doesn't work in scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to show/hide something using angular but when it's called via `$scope` it doesn't work. If I change the show variable with `ng-model` it works fine.

```
<div id="editClient"
     class="accordeon panel-group" 
     role="tablist" 
     aria-multiselectable="true" 
     ng-show="show">
     ....
</div>
```

And in my script this doesn't work.

```
client.controller('clientController', function($scope) {
  $scope.show = true;

  $scope.test = function() {
    alert('clicked'); 
    $scope.show = true;
}
```

The "clicked" is shown and I tried to use `$apply`, too, but result is the same.

But when I use `ng-model` it works

```
<input type="checkbox" value="true" ng-model="show">
```

Can someone explain me why it doesn't work with `$scope.show` ?

Comment: Nothing can be said from your code. Please provide a jsFiddle or put your complete code here ..

Comment: My elements where not in my controller -_- ! thanks you make me read myt code

Comment: For starters you initially set `show` to `true` and to... `true` again.

Answer (score 1):

Debug.

Following works just fine using checkbox with ng-bind and button firing function in controller.

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="show">Toggle visibility
<br>
<button type="button" ng-click="toggle()">Toggle visibility</button>
<hr>
<div ng-show="show">Visible</div>
<div ng-show="!show">Hidden</div>
```

---

```
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.show = true;

  $scope.toggle = function() {
    $scope.show = !$scope.show;
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Following works fine using `$scope`. See jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/ffKTy/312/